# "error: expected primary-expression before '.' token" shows up and I don't know why

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Im quite new to C++ and I'm not sure why does "string c = print.say(z);" produce an error, if i put it in either main or the while loop in main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class print {
    public:
    int x;
    string say(int x) {
    switch (x) {
    case 1: return "text1";
    case 2: return "text2";
    case 3: return "text3";
    default: return "default";} } };

int main() {
    int y = 1;
    int z = 1;
    while (y == 1) {
    cin >> z;
    string c = print.say(z);
    cout << c; } }
```

Comment: There is no `print` object.

Comment: print().say(z);

Comment: You can't just call members of a class. You need an object of that class.

Comment: Your class doesn't use its data member and the parameter of `say` shadows it. You might as well turn this class into a free function. It looks like that's what you were going for in trying to use it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just had to do this:

```
int main() {
    print print;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 1;
    while (y == 1) {
    cin >> z;
    string c = print.say(z);
    cout << c; } }
```

Comment: `print print;` I would advise you to never ever do this. Make your code readable and to avoid other problems. Meaning don't name an object exactly the same as the class.

Comment: Please dont use the type name as the variable name, not only is it confusing, in certain cases you'll get cryptic errors.

Comment: right now im just testing.
how should i name it in actual code?

Comment: Pick something different from `print`

Comment: @IwanTrajanowski Just as you want. You can just name it printObject if you want it to be clear in your mind.

Comment: is this alright?:

int main() {
    print pr;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 1;
    while (y == 1) {
    cout << "Choose a number from 1 to 3: ";
    cin >> z;
    string c = pr.say(z);
    cout << c; } }

Comment: I say that this is fine. With that said, the naming that @BenjaminBarrois suggested would be better because it is more descriptive. Remember a big part of writing code is making the code readable / self documenting. When someone else reads `pr` they would question what that means more than they would when they read `printObject`.